# SQL asks for Parameter Value after checking columns names

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm running a query to search for mismatching values between a master table and other linked tables. The problem is that I'm getting a "Enter Parameter Value" on DIS_ID and three more. Any thoughts on that?

```
SELECT * 
FROM FILES f 
WHERE   f.Network_ID not in (SELECT Network_ID from Networks) OR
    f.[009_Network] not in (SELECT Network_Code from Networks) OR

    f.[LINE1_ID] not in (SELECT LINE_ID from LINE) OR
    f.[Line 1] not in (SELECT Line_Code from LINE) OR

    f.[Trans_ID] not in (SELECT Trans_ID from Transportation_Mode) OR
    f.[Transportation_Mode] not in (SELECT Mode from Transportation_Mode) OR

    f.[Discipline_ID] not in (SELECT DIS_ID from DISCIPLINE) OR
    f.[012_Discipline] not in (SELECT [Dis Code] from DISCIPLINE) OR

    f.[013_System] not in (SELECT [Sys Code] from Systems) OR
    f.[System_ID] not in (SELECT System_ID from Systems);
```

Comment: Check your column/table name carefully.  Side note: You could switch to using `EXISTS` clauses for a possible performance gain.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I've checked my column and table very carefully. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the use of EXISTS?

Comment: What data does SELECT DIS_ID from DISCIPLINE return, or does it ask for a parameter value. Also, what are the "three more" you refer to?

Comment: DIS_ID, Sys Code, and DIS Code.
It returns null

Comment: Avoid space in the Field name. It asking to `Enter Parameter Value` because of column name mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created some of these tables and the query and it works fine. 
See the attached picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bwlk.jpg)